# Jquery UI Autcomplete Not Working

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am attempting to implement the jquery UI Autocomplete feature and I am having all sorts of troubles. I originally got a "autcomplete not a function" error, but moving all of my script references into the bottom of the body made that error go away (for unknown reason). Now the autocomplete is simply not working and I'm not getting any more errors. I originally was using my own code but since it didn't work I swapped over to an example just to get things going.

Here is the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="content/js/custom/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="content/js/custom/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="content/js/custom/jquery.ui.position.min.js"></script>
<script src="content/js/custom/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#auto" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
</script>
```

Edit: Finally got the html to show up. Here is the input field

```
<input type="text" id="auto" name="auto"/>
```

I have checked all of the imports and as far as I can tell, they all can be found and I have all the dependencies. I'm running this on Mozilla Firefox 5.0 in Windows XP.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: could you please show a full example: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Am I missing any information that would help you? I'm not sure I fully understand jsfiddle or why running my code on that would make a difference

Comment: jsfiddle lets you create a page people can edit (html, JS, CSS) which illustrates your problem. In the example above there isn't a 'auto' input field, or any of the HTML body actually

Comment: In my actual code I have an input field named "auto," but as I commented in the original post, I'm not sure how to get the HTML to show up.

Comment: HTML is treated the same as your JS code etc, paste it in and appply the 'code' formatting

Comment: I have edited the original post to include the input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this way.I have done like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='path/jquery.autocomplete.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#input_id").autocomplete(["ab","cd"]);
});
}); 
</script>
</head>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I do that, I get the error "$(document).ready is not a function"

Comment: To get rid of the document.ready is not a function error, I had to add a line "jQuery.noConflict();" at the beginning of the script tag. I changed the $ to jQuery as well. I also had to move jquery-1.6.1.min.js back up to the top of the page (all the others are at the end of the body) and now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

I've copied your code into a jsfiddle (link follows) which works.

I'd use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to ensure that all the JavaScript files are loading as you'd expect, and that there are no erros.

If not check your webserver logs.

http://jsfiddle.net/m6ST6/1/